# Apply patch, exclude a specific folder

Tags: shell, magento, updates, patch

I have a patch file for some software (Magento) and want to apply it to my current project.

The patch file contains also references to files in the `var/packages` folder which I do not want (I deleted this folder in my installation).

When applying this patch file (`patch -p1 < the.patch`), I get lots of warnings like:

```
The next patch would delete the file var/package/Foo_Bar.1.7.0.0.xml,
which does not exist!  Assume -R? [n] ^C
```

Is there any way to tell the patch command to just ignore patches for this folder?

Comment: Just wondering... Why you deleted that folder?

Comment: Actually I .gitignore /var - even Magento 2 does this (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/.gitignore) so it can't be that wrong. And I do not use Magento Connect which I believe is the reason for those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the “filterdiff” utility – http://man.cx/filterdiff – from http://packages.debian.org/patchutils to do that.

Otherwise, just pressing Enter a lot will also help ;-)

Comment: Pressing enter a lot might cause errors as I might oversee errors which are actually important.

Comment: Right, but if pre-filtering the patch works for you… have fun! ;-)

Comment: Instead of pressing enter: `yes '' | patch -p1 -i the.patch` or `patch -p1 -f < the.patch`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filterdiff`](http://man.cx/filterdiff) from the [`patchutils`](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Patchutils) package.

> `-x *PATTERN*, --exclude=*PATTERN*`
>
> Exclude files matching *PATTERN*. All other lines in the input are displayed.

So for your example

```
filterdiff -p1 -x 'var/packages/*' < the.patch | patch -p1
```

Alternatively you can manually edit the patch to remove the unwanted files, but this make take some time if it's very large.